# Windows Server 2012 R2 DNS internal and external records issue

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running  into an issue with with DNS on Windows Server 2012 R2 acting as Active Directory domain controller AND DNS server

I want to be able to setup certain records that will resolve internally using the local DNS server but if record is not present, the request is sent for external DNS query. Is this possible with Windows Server 2012R2?

ZONE

[internal records managed by windows server 2012 DNS server]

something.com

```
sub1    A   10.10.0.1
sub2    A   10.10.0.2
sub3    CNAME sub1.something.com.
```

---

[external records managed by external DNS provider]

something.com

```
sub4    A    54.26.45.24
sub5    A    184.34.56.25
sub6    CNAME   images.cdnprovider.net.
```

So basically i want to be to direct users to internal resources if requesting the records(for example sub1.something.com, sub2.something.com and sub3.something.com) in the internal DNS and if those records do not exist (for example sub4.something.com, sub5.something.com and sub6.something.com) then it should go out and resolve appropriately

I am trying to do this so i don't have to copy all records from external DNS provider to internal DNS. So that way i only add the records that need to be resolved locally and for the ones not added locally then it should go out and resolve.

Can i do this?

If my question is not very clear please let me know and i will edit it right away.

UPDATED: 
Basically something that works same way hosts file work on Windows OS(and others as well), where if the records are present then it uses local host records and if not it goes out.

Thanks

Comment: This can't presently be done with Windows DNS.

Comment: @joeqwerty I know some people are doing this so what solution are people using then for something like this?

Comment: If you know that some people are doing this why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described, it's not possible. If other people are "doing this" then you should ask them. Otherwise, the only answer is to manually enter those records in to your DNS.

And this is just one of the reasons that you should create your Active Directory forest in a subdomain.

Comment: ActiveDirectory was created with `.local` and domain is created as new ZONE..so i mean making it subdomain doesn't help anyways as i am not able to solve my problem

Comment: Using `.local` is a bad idea. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726016. If your companies domain is `example.com` (usually the one where you receive emails) consider using a subdomain for your domain, such as `internal.example.com` or `ad.example.com` or similar to your liking. But not `example.local`!

Comment: really confused now..i thought the advice is to use `.local`...most tutorials i see use `.local` and recommend to use `.local` So can you please give a specific scenario where `.local` is bad? i mean trying to understand this..thanks

Comment: Those tutorials are perpetuating old advice. `.local` was Microsoft's first suggestion when they created Active Directory, but they quickly changed their advice to a subdomain.

Comment: if i decide to use split brain, and manage records both internally and externally, how can i have a way to auto-sync records between external and internal? so that way both internal and external always have same records? doesn't matter if time takes like 5 to 15 minutes before sync completes

Comment: Using what's in the box, you don't. It's either manual or not.